# Wildfly 8 não lê pasta de rede quando executado como serviço

Tags: java, imagem, wildfly, redes

Bom dia!

Tenho uma aplicação java 8 rodando no Wildfly 8, preciso exibir imagens.
A exibição funciona perfeitamente quando a pasta é local C: (Eclipse, CMD e Serviço).  Precisei transferir a pasta com as imagens para rede, criei o mapeamento.  Executei vários testes pelo Eclipse e iniciando o Wildfly pelo CMD do Windows, funcionou perfeitamente.  Quando executo pelo serviço do Wildfly no Windows, a pasta de rede não é encontrada (não encontra os arquivos), alguma dica?  Me parece um problema de permissão, mas como pode funcionar iniciando o Wildfly pelo Eclipse e Command do Windows?  Só não funciona como serviço...  Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Segue o código:

```
            final File[] files = (new File(dirOrigem)).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String nome) {
                    return nome.contains(name);
                }
            });

            ImagemAux imagemAux;
            for (File arquivo: files) {
                System.out.println("arquivo: " + arquivo);
```

Comment: Tentei configurar uma conta no serviço do Wildfly, mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: O que é `dirOrigem`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa É o mapeamento da pasta da rede que possui as imagens. dirOrigem: Z:\TEMP\imagens.